# Js chosen, how to update the dropdown when there is an update in the select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropdown, jquery-chosen

i use chosen js for my select option

but in my case there is some button that can trigger some section to be hidden,
so i want to update my dropdown to hide the section too.

this in before the section is hidden

```
<select id="course" name="" class="form-select chosen-select">
<option value="topbar">Jump to section</option>
<option id="sec1" value="section1">Section 1</option>
<option id="sec2" value="section2">Section 2</option>
<option id="sec2" value="section3">Section 3</option>
</select>
```

how to update the dropdown when the select option become like this

```
<select id="course" name="" class="form-select chosen-select">
<option value="topbar">Jump to section</option>
<option style="display:none;" id="sec1" value="section1">Section 1</option>
<option id="sec2" value="section2">Section 2</option>
<option id="sec2" value="section3">Section 3</option>
</select>
```

I already try .trigger("chosen:updated") and .trigger("liszt:updated) but still the dropdown not changing, i think i maybe use it wrong but the documentation about chosen is so few.
please someone help me :)
thanks

Update chosen js dropdown

Comment: Note that [tag:chosen] hasn't been updated for many years and is [currently deprecated](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/#this-version-of-chosen-is-not-currently-under-active-development-while-we-decide-on-its-future-direction) *"This version of Chosen is not currently under active development while we decide on its future direction."*

Comment: If `.trigger("chosen:updated")` is not working for you (as per your attempt and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52080181/2181514)) please provide a *complete* snippet of code that demonstrates your issue.  See the [SO chosen wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-chosen/info) for code, see also [mcve].

Comment: "*when the select option become[s] like this*" - exactly *how* does the select "become like this"?   Do you replace the `select` entirely?  Or do you just add display:none to the first option?  Please be specific.

Comment: `.trigger("chose:updated")` works fine for me:  https://jsfiddle.net/abgxz59k/